# Alinear dos divs con Bootstrap horizontal y verticalmente

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3, div

Tengo dos `divs` dentro de un contenedor que ocupa el 100% de la pantalla. Estos dos `divs` tienen distintos tamaños tanto de ancho como de alto, y quería alinearlos a ambos en el centro del `div` contenedor.

Dejo una imagen de lo que quiero lograr y mi código.

```html
<div class="row" style="margin: auto; height: 100%"> 

  <h2>¡Hola mundo!</h2>     

  <div class="col-lg-6">
    Soy el div grande naranja
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4"> 
    Soy el div más chico verde                         
  </div>

</div>
```

[image: Lo que quiero lograr]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A través de las clases `mx-auto` y `my-auto` que nos proporciona **Bootstrap** puedes centrar los `<div>` internos tanto verticalmente como horizontalmente.

```css
#contenedor {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 400px;
}

#naranja {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 300px;
}

#verde {
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="contenedor" class="row">
  <div id="naranja" class="col-6 my-auto mx-auto">
      Soy el div grande naranja
  </div>
            
  <div id="verde" class="col-4 my-auto mx-auto"> 
       Soy el div más chico verde                         
  </div>
</div>
```

Una alternativa sin el uso de las clases de **Bootstrap**:

```css
#contenedor {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 400px;
}

#naranja {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}

#verde {
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="contenedor" class="row">
  <div id="naranja" class="col-6">
      Soy el div grande naranja
  </div>
            
  <div id="verde" class="col-4"> 
       Soy el div más chico verde                         
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Estaba respondiendo lo mismo que tú, ahora me ha tocado eliminar lo que llevaba jajaja. Por cierto, esta es la forma más adecuada y simple de hacer lo que el OP pide. PD: Cabe aclarar que esto sólo funcionaría con BS en su verisón 4, de lo contrario con copiar las clases bastaría.

Comment: Yo estoy usando la versión 3.4.0 de BS. En ese caso, solo copio las clases que puso en los divs? Eso es lo que quieres decir?

Comment: Realmente estoy un poco en contra de utilizar clases de **Bootstrap** que aportan pocas reglas **CSS** con el fin de evitar que tus elementos adquieran una lista interminable de clases que complican muchas veces la lectura del **HTML**. Por esto mismo edito mi respuesta para presentar una alternativa.

Comment: Claro, en mi caso, estos divs no tienen un tamaño de alto fijo, sino que están hechos para ser adaptables. Por eso pregunto si en necesario que les ponga un alto fijo para que funcione el `margin: auto`

Comment: No, no es necesario, con un `height` dinámico también funcionaría.

Comment: Bueno, por alguna razón no me lo toma. Pero igualmente selecciono esto como respuesta, porque de seguro es algo que hice mal yo. Ahora voy a revisar todo el código. Muchas gracias

Answer (score -1):

mira debería ser así para que salga como en la imagen, en caso de no ser así te recomiendo que te metas a w3schools ahí encuentras una respuesta mas certera a tu pregunta:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <h3>Este es el contenedor 1</h3>
      <p>Soy el div grande naranja</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <h3>Column 2</h3>
      <p>Soy el div mas chico verde</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Espero haberte ayudado suerte!.:D

Comment: Si no, puedes usar un div class=container distinto para cada uno y le modificas los estilos directamente desde la etiqueta para que el html tome prioridad a esos y no al del bootstrap.min.css

Comment: Esto no responde a la pregunta, es más, no tiene diferencias relevantes respecto al código que el OP presenta. Estarías haciendo lo mismo que ya tiene.